# Undefined variable on line 34 php

Tags: php, html, database

My code:

```
<?php
 include("funcoes.php");

?>

<HTML>
<HEAD>
  <META charset = "UTF-8">

  <TITLE>Menu</TITLE>
</HEAD>
<BODY>

<center>
  <form method="POST" >
    Marca: <input type="text" name="marca"></a><BR>
    Preço: <input type="number" name="preco"></a><BR>
    Polegadas: <input type="number" name="tamanho"></a><BR>
    Tipo de Tela: <select name="tipoTela">
    <option value="1"> LED</option>
    <option value="2"> LCD</option>
    <option value="3"> Plasma</option>
    <option value="4"> CRT</option>
    <option value="5"> DLP</option>
  </select> <BR><BR>
    Formato:     <select name="formato">
    <option value="1"> Convencional</option>
    <option value="2"> Widescreen(HD)</option>
  </select> <BR><BR>
    Fabricante: <select name="fornecedor">
    <? $fornecedores = buscarFornecedores();
                    foreach ($fornecedores as $fornecedores) { ?>
    <option value="<? echo $fornecedores; ?>">
      <?php echo $fornecedores; ?> //linha 34
    </option>
    <? } ?>
  </select>
  </form>
  <center>
</BODY>
</HTML>
```

The function:

```
function buscarFornecedores (){
    echo "oi1";
    $qry = "SELECT * FROM public.fornecedor";
    $result = pg_query($qry) or die("Cannot execute query: $qry\n");

    while($row = pg_fetch_object($result)){

        $fornecedores[] = $row;
    }

    return $fornecedores;
}
```

The error is this:

Undefined variable: fornecedores in /var/www/cadastro.php on line 34

The problem is that in a computer of a friend, the same code works normally, with the same stuffs.

Comment: Have you tried renaming the new variable in the foreach? It could be a different version of PHP doesn't like foreach($x as $x) ??

Comment: Your array is out of scope if declared inside the loop. Conditional statements ignore scope, so a variable declared in "if" can be used outside the "if", but this is not the case for a loop such as this.

Answer (score 2):

You need to define the variable as an array before you start adding items to it:

```
function buscarFornecedores (){
    $fornecedores = array();
    ....
```

In PHP a variable will only be scoped to the function it is defined inside unless you use the `global` keyword. [More info on that here](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.variables.scope.php)

Seeing as you were trying to assign `$fornecedores` from the returned value of the function you would also have needed to define it anyway, in the global scope, before adding items to it as an array.

Comment: Yes and no, this has more to do with scoping than the type of variable. So your answer is correct, but some explanation would be rockin ;)

Comment: Woohoo for education! That's why we're all here after all

Comment: I add the $fornecedores = array(); but the error still hapenning.

Comment: I would try using separate variable names in the for loop too: `foreach ($fornecedores as $f) {`

Comment: I changed this too, but the same error still hapenning =/. The difference is that appears 'f' istead 'fornecedor' in the error

Answer (score 0):

Your foreach loop says

```
foreach($fornecedores as $fornecedores) {}
```

You're using the same variable name for the elements of your result list.

Comment: <? $fornecedores = buscarFornecedores();
                foreach ($fornecedores as $f) { ?>
                    <option value="<? echo $f; ?>">
                     <?php echo $f; ?> //linha 34
                    </option>       
     <? } ?>

Comment: If this still throws an error on linha 34, please show me a var_dump of $fornecedores before the loop.

Answer (score 0):

This error was fixed when I restart the postgres and the apache in my ubuntu.
Thanks for the answers. You find errors that I had not seen.
=D